# import scss in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, ecmascript-6

I have this webpack.config file:

```
const path = require('path')

var config = {
   entry: './src/index.js',
   output: {
      path:'/',
      filename: 'bundle.js',
   },
   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080,
      historyApiFallback: {
        index: 'index.html'
      }
   },
   module: {
     loaders: [
       {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
      },
    ]
   },
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), "node_modules"]
    }
}
module.exports = config;
```

and when I want to import a style I get this error:

Uncaught Error:

> Cannot find module "./style.scss" at webpackMissingModule (bundle.js:77680) at Object.defineProperty.value (bundle.js:77680) at webpack_require (bundle.js:20) at Object.defineProperty.value (bundle.js:77611) at webpack_require (bundle.js:20) at Object.defineProperty.value (bundle.js:77047) at webpack_require (bundle.js:20) at Object.defineProperty.value (bundle.js:50608) at webpack_require (bundle.js:20) at Object.defineProperty.value (bundle.js:50310)

and this is the component:

```
...
import './style.scss';

class Solution extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}

export default Solution;
```

the scss file is in the same folder has the component.

Comment: What version of Webpack are you using?

Comment: @Jaxx i am using v3.8.1

Comment: Then your CSS/SCSS loaders should be `[ "style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader" ]`

Comment: @Jaxx i am still getting the same error

Comment: Do you have the `node-sass` module installed? (as a dev dependency, so use --save-dev if installing)

Comment: @Jaxx yes i have it installed as dev

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Do you have a github repo where I can look at the entire project and eventually download it locally to try & figure it out?